Commutator subgroup of complex reflection group
Is it true that every (irreducible finite dimensional) complex reflection groups is either solvable or has a perfect commutator subgroup?
Lots of cases are easy, like the commutator subgroup of $ S_n $ is $ A_n $, and the groups with Shephard-Todd (ST) numbers 23,24,27,32,33,36, which are
$$
2 \times A_5,2 \times GL(3,2), 2 \times 3.A_6, 3 \times Sp(4,3), 2 \times PSp(4,3),2 \times Sp(6,2)
$$
are all direct product of a cyclic group with a quasisimple group, so the commutator subgroup is just the quasisimple factor in the direct product. In all these examples (of non-solvable groups) it is easy to see what the commutator subgroup is and to verify that it is perfect.
In general I am just curious, how do you find the commutator subgroup of a complex reflection group? For example I am interested in the commutator subgroup of the complex reflection group with ST number 31, which has structure
$ 2^{2+4}.Sp(4,2)$. This group is clearly not solvable, but it is not obvious to the naked eye that the commutator subgroup is perfect. Since (irreducible finite dimensional) complex reflection groups have such a nice structure I was wondering if there is some nice way to determine the structure of the commutator subgroup, its order, is it perfect etc...
I would be open to both a conceptual approach to understanding the commutator subgroup, or a more computational approach like using GAP.

In the example you mentioned $2^{2+4}.{\rm Sp}(4,2)$, the commutator subgroup has index $2$ and is indeed perfect. (I don't like your use of $*$, which usually denotes a free product.)

@DerekHolt ok I changed to your notation ( I just took the original notation from the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group), you are right that $ * $ is usually for free product. I suppose $ 4 \circ_2 2^{1+4} $ would be more standard notation for central product if I really wanted to write it that way?
